# Using socket.io to send data to a specific view/id

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a web application using NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB. In my application, I have a view, that can be seen by anyone who accesses the application. That view is rendered with a different image, depending on which a user selects to view (they do not need to be logged in) ie the view is mapView/mapId.

Now, I want something similar to notifications to occur in realtime for those that are on that page. When a specific event happens from an external source, I want to display a popup on the view to which the event belongs to. So the event may only belong to one mapView/mapId and not another mapView with a different ID. All users on the same mapView/mapId should see the notification. Remember, these are general users that do not need to be logged in.

I am researching into Socket.io because I know it is for making realtime applications. But I am wondering if this is even the right way to go. How will I send data to the correct mapView/mapId?

Comment: Can you please include code examples of a specific problem you are having? This question is difficult to answer without specific code to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what your [server can do with rooms](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#join(name:string[,-fn:function]):socket)

The idea is that each of your connections, from a particular view, is joined to a room. Then you use socket.io from the server to send a message only to that room. And only those sockets will get the message.

Comment: Cool!! When you say particular view. mapView/12345 is a different view from mapView/6789 right? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Right. You can make a different room for each of those. One the server, when you know that connection is in that view, the server subscribes that socket to the room `socket.join('12345')`. When the user changes views, your server will need to `socket.leave('12345'` that room, and `.join` the new one.